# Javascript different Carousel with same Layout/Style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been puzzled by a thing these days, tried to google but didn't find anything that would help my case, not sure whether someone asked this but looks like did not (at least not as specific).

What I'm troubled with is :
I have a section with 4 different (put only 2 in the code) vertical divs which I want each to trigger a different Lightbox/Carousel on click.
What I have atm is the code below (without CSS where I only have the styling of Slides and Modal/Carousel layout).

**Problem** 
What I lack is the knowledge as to how to trigger different carousels with same Modal/Carousel layout I styled in CSS. for example I would like the second Slide to trigger a Lightbox/Carousel containing images 3.jpg and 4.jpg.

Cheers and have a nice day. Thanks in advance.

I'm still a beginner so most likely I have some useless pieces of code which is not being used.

HTML

```
<section class="row" id="gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
 <div class="slide" alt="First slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-slide-to="0" >
      <div class="content">
        <h2> Pre-Wedding</h2>
        <p>Bla-bla-bla-bla</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" alt="Second slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"  data-slide-to="0">
      <div class="content">
        <h2> Groom</h2>
        <p>Bla-bla-bla-bla</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block " src="1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block " src="2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>

                 ...other Images

              </div>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('gallery').classList.add("custom");
document.getElementById('exampleModal').classList.add("custom");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to. 
basically i changed the CSS from this

CSS

```
#exampleModal.custom{
...
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('gallery').classList.add("custom");
document.getElementById('exampleModal').classList.add("custom");
```

to this

CSS

```
#exampleModal.custom, #carouselone.custom{
...
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('gallery').classList.add("custom");
document.getElementById('exampleModal').classList.add("custom");
document.getElementById('carouselone').classList.add("custom");
```

So now by changing ID and data-target it triggers the same layout with different content(images).
Not sure wether it is the most efficient way but hey..it works